# Having trouble avoiding subclassing

Tags: ios, swift, subclass

I have an app with multiple view controllers. I am implementing a search bar to navigate a *table view* that is in each of these view controllers.

I have chosen to implement the search controller using a custom class, where I handle all the search logic. In order to make this possible, I am currently using a superclass from which each view controller inherits. I would like to know if there is a way for me to make this work **without** subclassing.

Here is the current implementation of my `SearchController` class:

```
class SearchController: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {

    /* This is the trouble spot. If I change this to UIViewController?, 
       I get the compiler error "value of type UIViewController has no member tableView" */
    weak var viewController: BaseViewController?  

    /*
      ... rest of SearchController implementation

      includes methods that interact with view controller table views
    */
}
```

this is the `BaseViewController` class:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    let searchController = SearchController()
    let tableView = UITableView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)

    /*
      ... rest of BaseViewController implementation
    */

}
```

To summarize, the issue I am having is that I have several view controllers with tableviews and I can't seem to make this work without creating a new base class that they can inherit from. Using `UIViewController` simply won't work because the UIViewController class does not have a `tableView` property built into it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you make `BaseViewController` inherit from `UITableViewController` in that case? You can also share common functionality through `protocol`s, you don't necessarily need to use inheritance.

Comment: I could make `BaseViewController` inherit from `UITableViewController`, although what I am doing right now is just have each view controller use `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` and taking the longcut. I think protocols would be the way to go.

Comment: Question about using protocols in this situation: would I have to replace this `SearchController` class altogether with something like a `Searchable` protocol, or should I use them together?

Comment: Without more context it's quite hard to give specific advice, since both solutions should work in general.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to force all your viewControllers to subclasses BaseViewController. If the only requirement is for the viewController to have a tableView property then define a protocol with that requirement and make the relevant viewControllers implement that protocol.
Rewriting your example:

```
protocol BaseControllerProtocol: class {
    var tableview: UITableView { get }
}

class SearchController: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {

    //We store any class that implements the BaseControllerProtocol protocol
    //Now you can use viewController.tableview
    weak var viewController: BaseControllerProtocol?
    //If you what to have UIViewcontrollers instances only use:
    //weak var viewController: (UIViewController & BaseControllerProtocol)?
}

//An example of a viewcontroller that implements the BaseControllerProtocol
class ARandomViewController : UIViewController, BaseControllerProtocol {
    var tableview: UITableView = UITableView()
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the right idea, however I have some problems with this. The main issue is that inside my `SearchController` class I have a delegate method from `UISearchBarDelegate` called `textDidChange`. In this method, I make my search return different results based on which VC is currently using it. In order to use the protocol you mentioned, I would have to export this functionality from `SearchController` to the `extension`. If I do that, every variable is out of scope and I get a bunch of errors (since many of the variables used in `textDidChange` are class propertieso fSeachController

Comment: If it helps, in the textDidChange you could check for the VC class type, and act differently depending on the VC that is using it, for example:                       func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        guard let viewController = viewController else {
            return
        }
        if let randomController = viewController as? ARandomViewController {
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I think you could still use `UIViewController?` if you assign its `UITableView` to your `SearchViewController`'s private `tableView` calculated instance variable like so:

```
class SearchController: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {
    weak var viewController: UIViewController?

    fileprivate var _tableView: UITableView? {
        if let vc = self.viewController {
            for subview in vc.view.subviews {
                if let tableView = subview as? UITableView {
                    return tableView
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    // Whatever methods interact with table view should now use self._tableView.
    func doSomething() {
        guard let tableView = self._tableView else { return }
        // Do something with the tableView
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use `UITableViewController` instead of `UIViewController`?